# Entity Framework - How do create an association to/from the same entity?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

In Entity Framework (VS2010) how do I create an association to/from the same table?  (a many-to-many is what I want)

Background - I was expecting under the bonnet a NODE and RELATIONSHIP table, where the latter has a parent_node_id and a child_node_id (i.e. pointing back to the NODE id column).  I can't seem to get the designer to add it...

Comment: Can u please explain little more u problem. 
If u have created the relationship in DB then  when u update your model association is automatically created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Model first: create entity, right click: add association, select same Entity, mark it Many to many on both ends.

Database first: create two tables: Node and Edge, Edge contains two Node references.  (Using appropriate PK, FK's).

Comment: thanks - seems to work at work, however wasn't at home before - I wonder if my VS2010 running under VMFusion was doing something funny - I'll try again tonight from home